# Node client updates require where they should not be according to Polkadot's release notes

Tags: polkadot, runtime-upgrade, upgrade

I am working on a Substrate node update.

I am following [Polkadot's releases](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases) not to skip migrations.

Some node runtime updates require node client updates. This information can be found in Polkadot's releases. For example, [v0.9.0](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.0) or [v0.9.8](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.8).

During testing on dev networks, I found out that [v0.8.27](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.8.27) and [v0.9.5](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.5) also require node client updates. I am receiving the following error during connection to a node after node runtime applying via forkless upgrade:

```
FATAL: Unable to initialize the API: -32603: Unknown error occurred: Client, VersionInvalid, Other, \"Instantiation: Export ext_default_child_storage_storage_kill_version_2 not found\
```

Can it be missed information in Polkadot's release logs or is something wrong on my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely that these information are just missing in the Polkadot release logs.

Especially for these old releases.